# Transaction.commit throwing arguement null exception in entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

```
var context = UnitOfWork._context;
 configurationContext.Database.CommandTimeout = 1200;
 using (var transaction = context .Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable)){

select some data based on inner join

if data is already there update 

else insert

context.SaveChanges();
transaction.Commit();
```

This is working for single user in single environment.
But if a single user is doing transactions concurrently,it is throwing below exceptions

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: 'The underlying provider failed on Commit.'

Inner exception 
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: connection
```

Anyidea why this behaviour is occuring?

If I replace System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable with empty,it is working fine,but I want to set it as serializable,so that no concurrent transactions can enter the same rows.

Comment: I think because the context has only a single connection in this use case, so the first completed operation is closing it?  I believe EF isn't designed to service multiple concurrent requests, at least not within a single context instance?

Comment: @GPW-But then how is it working without giving isolation level and every seperate transaction has a seperate context and hence seperate connection.

Comment: Can you post a short, complete repro?  Also why are you using Serializable?  You should almost never do that in SQL Server.

Comment: @ David Browne - Microsoft- It is coming which I am trying to send concurrent requests for single user to update his product info if exists or create new.Which isolation level should be used,i think serialization is best for concurrent transactions,since it hold lock?

Comment: Use READ COMMITTED, with lock hints if necessary.  SERIALIZABLE isn't really very useful.

Comment: This feature is completely BROKEN.  If you call Database.BeginTransaction, and then you call Database.SqlQuery <<< That ENDS the transaction. Before calling Database.SqlQuery, the Database.CurrentTransaction is populated, and after calling it, the transaction is GONE. So basically you cannot call BeginTransaction and then call SqlQuery to run a stored procedure that affects and returns data. It just wipes out your transaction. Opening the Connection before calling BeginTransaction doesn't help. It still ends it.  The only way around is to just not use EF. It's transaction management is flawed.